# Need help with LED spotlight and Driver

Tags: electrical, led

I have a problem with my driver which doesn’t power up my currently 4 Led GU5.3 bulbs 5W. The driver is LPV-60-12.
I want to install 10 spotlight in a parallel wire.

I have 4 LED Spotlight bulb GU5.3 5W each, as in the first picture.
I have a LED Power supply driver, LPV-60-12, as in the second picture.
I'm trying to wire the 4 LEDs in a parallel wire, with the driver, and the leds are not turning on at all.

What could be the problem?
Some photos below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the driver does not work now you need a new driver.

Comment: I tested the driver and it worked with a Led strip, but not with my bulbs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'll learn a lot if you'll spend a moment to read through the [tour]. It'll help you get the hang of this place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulbs are AC170-265V ie non-US mains voltage [EU, UK & others]

The driver outputs 12V - nowhere near enough.
[Picture shows a 60-36, but OP says it's a 60-12, which is only a 12V output rather than 36V.]

The bulbs don't need a driver, they need mains power.
You need to make sure your wiring can handle 240V. Low-voltage wiring will not do.
If you can't ensure that, you need to swap to low-voltage bulbs.

Data from https://www.meanwell.co.uk/led-drivers/constant-voltage-led-drivers/non-dim/lpv-60-series